# How to parse a JSON file in Python which is generated using Java Jackson with `DefaultTyping` enabled?

Tags: java, python, json, jackson

For a JSON sample attached below, for non-primitive class attributes, Jackson adds the class path, but it is difficult to parse it in Python.

One way to fix this is to disable Default Typing in Jackson while storing the files but is it possible to do it without changing the file creation? Any Python utility would be great.

```
{
  "stringAttribute": "some Value",
  "listAttribute": [
    "java.util.ArrayList",
    [
      "A",
      "B"
    ]
  ]
}
```